# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for ID is already being tracked

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I know there is a lot of questions about this but I've not been able to resolve it with them.
I'm doing a delete test method creating an object first to be sure there is something to delete. But because of that I got the instance error and I don't have any clue about how to fix it.

My code:

```
public async Task CanDeleteSignal()
{
     var s = new SignalsDTO()
     {
         Name = "Signal",
         TagType = "String",
         Description = "Foo"
     };

     int id = await _handler.Create(s);

     var delete = await _handler.Delete(id);
     var signalDelete = _handler.GetSignalsById(id).Result;
     Assert.IsTrue(delete);
     Assert.IsNull(signalDelete);
}
```

The object is created properly but when I want to delete I cannot because of this error.

Comment: What's a handler?

Comment: Long story short, every time you query a db with EF, unless you explicitly told it not to, EF remembers everything you've downloaded. If that memory contains some item of type X with ID 123 you cannot create and attach another object of type X with ID 123. If you've already done something to check that a 123 exists you should retrieve that entity that is already being tracked locally and delete it, rather than create and attach another

Comment: My handler is like a repository. I tried to make some changes to my code but still nothing.  My object is created as normal and it goes to the db after "Create" method but when I debug "Delete" is where it fails because of the instance. I don't know why is that because I'm just taking the returned id on create and passing it as a param on Delete, It should be like that no?

Comment: Maybe, but obviously not how it is written at the moment; either way, it's difficult to help you because you haven't actually posted the code that does the work!!